# Return type is a template of templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class:

```
  class Inject{ 

       template<template <class> class Daemon>
       RETURNTYPE register_inj();
  }
```

There are a number of implementation to this template function where the template arguments are explicitly specified one example is returning a class `ServiceA` which has one template argument that in this case is chosen to be class `CacheA`. The rule is that the template function will always have one template argument, but that template argument can have multiple template template arguments. E.g. `ServiceB<typename A, typename B>`

For `serviceA` the funtion template is implemented to:

```
   template<>
   auto register_inj<ServiceA<CacheA>> 
   { impl... }
```

My question is what should `RETURNTYPE` be set to in the header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question mixes two separate things.

1. The number of template arguments of the function template argument `Daemon` has nothing to with the return type. In fact, your specialisation for `ServiceA` indicates that you are not even asking for a template template argument. `ServiceA<CacheA>` is *not* a template - it is a normal type (which happens to be an *instantiation of a template*). Your function should therefore simply be declared as `template <class Daemon> RETURNTYPE register_inj()`. It will then work with `ServiceA<CacheA>` as well as with `ServiceB<CacheB,ResolverB>` (both of them are just types). You only need a template template parameter if you are instantiating that template within the body of your function.
2. In the header, the function return type could simply be declared to `auto`. That effectively declares the function to have a [deduced return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction).
   However, you won't be able to use that function until it is defined (every call-site needs to know the return type of that function). You will therefore have to inline the function definition into your header as-well. If you want to avoid that, you will have to explicitly write the return type using meta-programming techniques, e.g. as follows:

```cpp
// you need at least a forward definition of your services here,
// as well as the return types

template <typename Cache>
class ServiceA<Cache>;

template <typename Cache, typename Resolver>
class ServiceB<Cache,Resolver>;

class ServiceARegisterResult;

template <typename Resolver>
class ServiceBRegisterResult<Resolver>;

namespace detail {

template <typename Service>
struct register_inj_return_type {};

template <typename Cache>
struct register_inj_return_type<ServiceA<Cache>> : {
 using type = ServiceARegisterResult;
};

template <typename Cache, typename Resolver>
struct register_inj_return_type<ServiceB<Cache,Resolver>> : {
 using type = ServiceBRegisterResult<Resolver>;
};

} 
 
class Inject{ 

       template<class Daemon>
       typename detail::register_inj_return_type<Daemon>::type
       register_inj();
};
```